# how to have a widget inside a text?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a widget and want to have a drop down menu between a string of text in Flutter. How do I implement something like what the image show in Flutter?

[image: closed drop down]

[image: opened drop down]

Comment: I think you can't. The closet option is using flex properties in order to place a widget between two text widgets. I've done something similar to this in native android with web view and I think web view is the best approach.

Comment: thanks , can you share your android code for web view??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can split text string with every space in that text. and each splited text part be a seprate widget .so we can put a drop down widget between another widgets.for ex :

in question's example we should have 13 widget that 12 of them is Text widget and one of them is drop down widget . then we can put all this widgets in wrap widgets to show some thing like this picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. You can create a custom widget so you don't have to write the code always.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  String selectedItem = 'withdraw';
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Enemy troops chose to '),
              DropdownButton<String>(
                value: selectedItem,
                items: [
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: 'withdraw',
                    child: Text('withdraw'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: 'adverse',
                    child: Text('adverse'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: 'celebrate',
                    child: Text('celebrate'),
                  ),
                ],
                onChanged: (item) {
                  selectedItem = item;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
              Text(' to their camps, planning a new attack strategy.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```